# JavaFx : Set window title in fxml file

Tags: javafx-2

I'm just starting to use JavaFx for a new application.

I know how to set the window title in the java code but how to set it in a fxml file ?

Thanks for your help.

Edit :
Here is the code I have

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle(applicationName);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I just want set the title in Main.fxml.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to set the title of the stage in FXML, you need to construct the stage in FXML, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.stage.Stage?>
<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<Stage title="Some Stage">
  <scene>
    <Scene>
      <VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
        <children>
          <Label text="John Doe"/>
        </children>
      </VBox>
    </Scene>
  </scene>
</Stage>
```

If you only construct the root element of the scene (in my example, the VBox) via FXML and then put it into a scene afterwards like you do it (which is the common way), then it is impossible to set the title in FXML directly (without code behind).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: See [JavaFX Using alternative FXML structure for Title (Stage is root)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510606/javafx-using-alternative-fxml-structure-for-title-stage-is-root) for an example of how to use Sebastian's FXML.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.stage.Stage cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.Pane`